# Isekai about a village isekai boy selling modern stuff to peddlers/merchants

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Our hero (from modern-day Japan) invents modern stuff unheard of after he isekai-ed (as a child) into a medieval village. The village is poor as heck, being isolated in the medieval countryside of sorts and he most wishes to invent things to improve his fellow villagers' lives.

Things I recall

- I don't think there was a love interest.
- He's stuck there, no moving between worlds. It's a true reincarnation.
- No sex/nudity/gore either.
- The manga is in black-and-white, and has at least 10 chapters. Including the .1 & .2 ones.
- His 'enemies' are those merchants who are plain greedy and wanted to snatch the profit for themselves, using sneaky or underhanded means. Of course, they lost and got tied up eventually.
- The target audience is shounen, and we can even call it generic.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: A much improved question :-)

Comment: "*I Was Reincarnated As A Poor Farmer In A Different World, So I Decided To Make Bricks To Build A Castle"*?

Comment: sadly wrong answer...

Comment: What sorts of things did he invent?

Comment: Was there any magic in his new world, or was it just mundane?

Comment: My bad... I can't really remember the stuff he invented...... but we ain't getting anywhere like that.
Also no magic, pretty mundane.

Comment: I mean was it stuff like farming equipment or water wheels or more esoteric things like 'insurance' and 'production lines"

Comment: I think it was gamebreaking items that are so innovatic everyone can use it easily without any guide menu of sorts. Very practical.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283212/manga-where-a-five-year-old-boy-dies-and-is-reincarnated-to-another-world-as-a-c?noredirect=1&lq=1 got an answer, but the child's blessing is a magic dog, not future devices, at least of the four chapters I can find.

Comment: By "gamebreaking items" and "guide menu", do you mean he reincarnates into the world of a game, and the stuff he invents is explicitly items from the game? As opposed to real-world inventions like the waterwheel, pumps on a well, or beekeeping techniques?

Comment: Sadly, no. Game breaking here means highly innovative.

Comment: And he's not in a world of any video game, just some random isekai world

Answer (score 1):

OP, this matches, especially the farming tools and waterwheel part. But MC can go back and forth and is an adult, and theres a love story.

[I Won 4 Billion in a Lottery But I Went to Another World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ccsrnwr/takarakuji-de-40-oku-atatta-n-dakedo-isekai-ni-ijuu-suru)

Waterwheel in Chapter 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be *[Fushi no Kami: Rebuilding Civilization Starts with a Village](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/fushi-no-kami-rebuilding-civilization-starts-with-a-village)*.

> When the civilizations of yesteryear fade from memory and become fanciful fantasy, the only evidence of their existence...are books. Ash, a young boy living in a remote farming village, holds a secret—**he possesses memories of a distant and more bountiful past life**. Days of toiling in the fields have given rise to a burning desire: to bring more enjoyment to the everyday doldrum of his dreary present day! And while books may be the answer, Ash...can’t actually read! But where there is a will, there is a way. Join Ash as he battles illiteracy and **sets his sights on a better life**!

Synopsis covers the reincarnation aspect. He knows he had a previous life, but doesn't clearly remember anything, and doesn't know how to invent anything on his own. Instead, with the help of the village priest, he teaches himself to read with the intent of learning from the past.

His primary goal is to improve the quality of life for himself and therefore also the villagers.

[image]

The village he lives in is definitely poor, with almost all work going into farming and basically no healthcare. There are references throughout the series of people dying of minor fevers or injuries because there's basically no healthcare and not enough food.

There's no magic visible, but there are references to demons. No sex; there is a little gore involving a bear attack. There is a life interest, but it's one sided; the village chief's daughter is blatantly interested in Ash, but he remains oblivious and focused on learning from books. The demographic is shounen.

What doesn't match is the game breaking inventions, but that's rather subjective. His inventions are all fairly minor - new uses for herbs, beekeeping techniques (the beekeepers died before their craft could be taught to their children), literacy for other children and some adults, and a hand cream that can be sold to a trader for profit to buy essentials. There may be other inventions I'm forgetting, but on the whole everything is very subdued.

The merchant bit is also not a good match. He does encounter a merchant who tries to rip off his father by exploiting everyone's math illiteracy, until he corrects him. But that's the only merchant conflict - the merchant doesn't try anything beyond that, and becomes very friendly after Ash invents a hand cream he can sell in the capital.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was it [*Campfire Cooking in Another World with My Absurd Skill*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campfire_Cooking_in_Another_World_with_My_Absurd_Skill)?

> ... the adult, an ordinary salaryman named Tsuyoshi Mukouda (a.k.a. "Mukohda"), is found to only have the power of "Online Supermarket". Unwilling to become a hero and also suspicious of the kingdom's true intentions, he convinces the nobles his ability is useless, allowing him to leave and pursue a simple life in the new world. Experimenting with his Online Supermarket skill, he discovers he is able to instantly order food and other products from Japan.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please include relevant details from your link so that your answer stands in its own.

Comment: The lead is pulled to another world 'by accident' & left alone while the people he was next to get pulled into 'fighting demons to save their kingdom.' He can summon things from the supermarket, which ends up pretty powerful. I think he makes friends with the demons.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a particularly good match to the description given in the question... He doesn't Isekai as a child and he doesn't invent anything.

Comment: thanks for your answer....but unfortunately it isn't the one im asking for....

Comment: You know that tvtropes.org has manga/light novels listed, right? So, you can look up 'manga from 2016' & there's a list with links? I read a bunch of isekai summaries there. As long as someone thought to post it...

Comment: He's stuck there, no moving between worlds. It's a true reincarnation. 
Added this tag. How do i actually reject/reply to series assumptions here? They're wrong, both of them sadly.

Comment: @JokaKeekianKK There is no way to mark an answer as incorrect, only correct. Closest is to just add a comment saying so.

Comment: Sadge.... What a pity