# Manga where a five-year-old boy dies and is reincarnated to another world as a commoner

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

Looking for a recently released black and white Japanese manga (probably within the last 3-4 months), of a modern Japanese young child (3-5 years old) who dies and is reincarnated by a god to a commoner's family in another world. I read it online but can't find it in my history, so it's been translated to English somewhere. I think there were only 2-3 chapters available in English as well.

The god part might have just been a panel of a half face of a female god. It's not a big detail. The main part of my memory is that it's definitely a small child that gets reincarnated. As far as I know, there is no cheat skill or anything, because it's just a kid.

It's possible that he was put into an existing small child, who was dying due to fever, etc.

It's not:

- The isekai about the kid who eats magic stones and is a prince.
- *[Boku wa Imasugu Zense no Kioku wo Sutetai. - Akogare no Inaka wa Jingai Makyou deshita](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/c1zlptp/boku-wa-imasugu-zense-no-kioku-wo-sutetai-akogare-no-inaka-wa-jingai-makyou-deshita)*. (Although the art maybe reminded me of it.)

I could be crazy and mixing up manga in my head. If so, I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283043/isekai-about-a-village-isekai-boy-selling-modern-stuff-to-peddlers-merchants sound similar, but has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think its [Yasashii Kazoku to, Takusan no Mofumofu ni Kakomarete](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/kbxifgg/yasashii-kazoku-to-takusan-no-mofumofu-ni-kakomarete).

In chapter 1, mc dies at age ~6 and then after being reincarnated he shrinks to the age of ~3. 4 Chapters in english , but released in 2020.

There aren't many isekai of children. Usually isekai characters are high schoolers or office lady / businessmen / uncle aka "ossan". Some isekai are with senior citizens.

(i couldnt finish my account setup as crazyontheinside. so i'm answering my own question).

Comment: Answering your own question is encouraged when you spend such time on research.  Please see the [help] for account merging issues; I hope you can fix it.

Comment: If [crazyontheinside](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/170643/crazyontheinside) is a previous account of yours, please merge that account with your new one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain control over this question as well as the reputation you earned with that account. It will also prove that this question has genuinely been answered by the same person who asked it.